# How to start and stop usb camera streaming using openCV by clicking a button and paint it into a custom widget on Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qt5

I'm quite new on qt. I'm trying to create a tab on my ui that can give the option to count how many usb cameras are connected to computer and list then using OPENCV. After that, I want to select one of then and start streaming a video into a custom widget, using paintEvent. My main difficulties are: how to start and stop a streaming when a button is pressed. Below i'm posting my code.

mainwindow.h

```
//includes...
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void on_CheckCamerasButton_clicked();
    void on_StartStreamingButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    cameraimage camera;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow(){
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_StartStreamingButton_clicked(){
    camera.startStreaming();
}

void MainWindow::on_CheckCamerasButton_clicked(){
    camera.stopStreaming();
}
```

cameraimage.h

```
//includes...
class cameraimage : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit cameraimage(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

private:
    QPoint mPoint;
    QTimer *timer;
    cv::VideoCapture captureVideo;

public slots:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event);
    void startStreaming();
    void stopStreaming();
};
#endif // CAMERAIMAGE_H
```

cameraimage.cpp

```
#include "cameraimage.h"

cameraimage::cameraimage(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    setMouseTracking(true);
}

void cameraimage::startStreaming(){
    qDebug() << "Starting Streaming";
    captureVideo.open(-1);
    if (captureVideo.isOpened() == false){
        qDebug() << "Camera can't open";
        return;
    }
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));

    timer->start(1);
}

void cameraimage::stopStreaming(){
    captureVideo.release();
    timer->stop();
}

void cameraimage::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *){
        cv::Mat tmpImage;
        cv::Mat image;
        captureVideo.read(tmpImage);

        if (tmpImage.empty() == true){
            qDebug() << "EMPTY!";
            return;
        }

        cv::cvtColor(tmpImage, image, CV_BGR2RGB);
        QImage img((const unsigned char*)(image.data), image.cols, image.rows, QImage::Format_RGB888);

        QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(img);
        QPainter painter(this);

        float comprimento = 1.0*width()/pixmap.width();
        float altura = 1.0*height()/pixmap.height();
        float ratio = 0.;

        if (comprimento<=altura)
            ratio = comprimento;
        else
            ratio = altura;

        QSize size = ratio*pixmap.size();
        size.setHeight(size.height()-10);

        QPoint p;
        p.setX(0 + (width()-size.width())/2);
        p.setY(5);
        painter.drawPixmap(QRect(p, size), pixmap.scaled(size, Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
}
```

I've got the following output after clicked on StartStreamingButton on MainWindow:

```
Starting Streaming...
EMPTY!
EMPTY!
EMPTY!
...
```

Can someone help me please?

Best regards :D

Comment: I've tested your code and it works fine, unless your pc is underperforming. What is your OS?

Comment: Here is my test: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/TestOpenCVQt

Comment: Years ago I worked in a project where I processed images, so time was a scarce resource, so use threads, maybe that's your choice.: https://github.com/eyllanesc/Mirosot-Peru/tree/master/Mirosot-PC

Comment: Hello @eyllanesc. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. Looking into your script I found my mistake. So, I just changed "camera.startStreaming()" to "ui->cameraImageWidget->startStreaming()". Now it's running. Thank you again for the help/programs/advices. Regards :)

Comment: Sure @eyllanesc ! Than becomes easier to help more people. Thank you again.